# Get Product Metafields Data with GraphQL / BigCommerce

Tags: graphql, bigcommerce

I'm trying to retrieve product metafields on BigCommmerce via GraphQL. The below code throws an error

```
query {
    site {
        product(entityId:639) {
          sku
          path
          metafields(namespace: "App_Namespace", keys: "color_key") {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                value
              }
            }
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Meta field information

```
Namespace App_Namespace
Key color_key
Description Colour
Value Blue | Grey | Yellow
```

Would appreciate any help on above. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The "keys" argument expects an array of keys. So even if you just want one key, submit it as an array of one:

```
query {
  site {
    product(entityId: 639) {
      sku
      path
      metafields(namespace: "App_Namespace", keys: ["color_key"]) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Check out this link for more examples:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/changelog#posts/graph-ql-storefront-api-updates-metafields-on-product-category-brand-variant

Comment: Thanks @Nathan Appreciate it. May have to keep an eye out on the change logs as the normal docs didn't point to the usage.

Comment: Hi @Nathan tried running the query and the response I get is -  "metafields": {"edges": []} Any ideas why it wouldn't output the value Blue | Grey | Yellow. I am using Metafield Manager to add the fields in so would assume the permissions would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to make sure that these requirements are met,
otherwise, even if the query is correct, you won't be able to get the metafields in the query:

The metafield must be marked with a permission_set of read_and_sf_access or write_and_sf_access in order to be exposed to the API. Metafields with any other permission value will be hidden.